# Configure service with Set-Service

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, powershell-3.0

Can I set a service to run in its own container thru Powershell? ie.

What is the Powershell equivalent of `sc config <service name> type= own`

Comment: What's wrong with using `sc`?

Comment: Pipe-lining becomes difficult. Once I identify an svchost hogging resources I want to put all the services in it in their separate containers and restart them, remotely thru Powershell-remoting, to identify the culprit service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change service type property on the corresponding WMI object.

```
# get service
$s = (Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "Name='Fax'")

# change service type
$s.Change($null, $null, 16) # 16 = "Own Process"
```

Other values you can find here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx)

Make sure that ReturnValue from change method is equal to 0. Meaning of error codes you can find in the link above.