# Powershell script replace sc config

Tags: powershell, sc

Good Day,

i look for a same command as

`sc config BITS type= own` in Powershell.
I think ist with
`set-service -name BITS -computername server1234 -idon´t know`

I have the problem that my INVOKE-COMMAND don´t work.
But all scripts work only this line don´t work.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverneedhelp -ScriptBlock {Start-Process cmd  -ArgumentList "/c 'sc config bits type= own'"}`

If anybody can help me, it is were so great.
Thankyou

Greeting
Jan

Comment: Have you tried just calling `sc.exe` directly instead of via `cmd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my script work it with

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverneedhelp -ScriptBlock {Start-Process cmd  -ArgumentList "/c sc config bits type= own"}
```

But I search a version of Powershell without cmd

Answer (score 0):

Run it directly?

```
Invoke-Command $serverneedhelp { sc config bits type= own }
```

The other alternative is with wmi:  [Configure service with Set-Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995712/configure-service-with-set-service)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old thread, but maybe someone would benefit from this.
What worked for me is:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverneedhelp -ScriptBlock {& SC.exe config "bits" type= own}
```